# How can I show that zero-one programming is not in APX?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, approximation, apx

How can I show that zero-one programming is not in APX?

- Vertex Cover Problem is in the APX class. So can I try a PTAS-reduction from the
  zero-one programming problem to Vertex Cover and show that there is no reduction
  between these problems?
- Where to begin with?
- Does someone maybe know a paper with a similar topic?

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Why do you want to show this ?

Comment: To show that APX is a proper subset of NPO.

Comment: I mean, do you need it for a paper, or a presentation, or ... ?

Comment: I need it for learning purposes. But primarily I would need a hint how to start with the subject.

Comment: Reduce a Log-APX hard, Poly-APX hard, Exp-APX hard, or NPO hard problem into that problem, and you'll prove that it cannot be in APX as long as P  != NP.